# Erro on compile/run grails app 3.2.5 on Elementary OS

Tags: grails

Well, I create grails projects with version **3.1.10**, **3.2.0**, **3.2.3**, **3.2.4** with success.

When I use **3.2.5**, **3.2.6** or **3.2.7**, I have errors like this:

```
Download https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-test/3.2.6/grails-test-3.2.6.jar
| Error Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Command [compile] error: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

**My environment:**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I am using **sdk** do manager grails version:

**$ sdk use grails 3.x.x**

When use **3.2.5**, **3.2.6** or **3.2.7**, problems.

Steps with all version reported:

```
$ sdk use grails 3.x.x
$ grails create-app g3xx
$ cd g3xx
$ grails compile
```

With **3.2.5**:

```
*g325 $ grails compile --stacktrace
| Error Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error

    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.readCommandFile(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy:48)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.readCommandFile(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.findCommands(ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.groovy:44)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy:86)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCommands(AbstractProfile.groovy:438)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.AbstractJarProfileRepository$JarProfile.getCommands(AbstractJarProfileRepository.groovy:130)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:468)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
| Error Command [compile] error: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.createCommand(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy:83)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.createCommand(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.findCommands(ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.groovy:46)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy:86)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCommands(AbstractProfile.groovy:438)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.AbstractJarProfileRepository$JarProfile.getCommands(AbstractJarProfileRepository.groovy:130)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:468)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Command [compile] error: null*
```

With **3.2.6**:

```
g326 $ grails compile --stacktrace
| Error Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error

    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.readCommandFile(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy:48)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.readCommandFile(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.findCommands(ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.groovy:44)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy:86)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCommands(AbstractProfile.groovy:438)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.AbstractJarProfileRepository$JarProfile.getCommands(AbstractJarProfileRepository.groovy:130)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:468)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: startup failed:
CreateScaffoldController.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
 @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
| Error Command [compile] error: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.createCommand(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy:83)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.GroovyScriptCommandFactory.createCommand(GroovyScriptCommandFactory.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.factory.ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.findCommands(ResourceResolvingCommandFactory.groovy:46)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy:86)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CommandRegistry.findCommands(CommandRegistry.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCommands(AbstractProfile.groovy:438)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.AbstractJarProfileRepository$JarProfile.getCommands(AbstractJarProfileRepository.groovy:130)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:468)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Command [compile] error: null
```

With **3.2.7**:

```
Unzipping /home/adriano/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-bin/71zneekfcxxu7l9p7nr2sc65s/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip to /home/adriano/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-bin/71zneekfcxxu7l9p7nr2sc65s
Set executable permissions for: /home/adriano/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-bin/71zneekfcxxu7l9p7nr2sc65s/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5 mins 24.911 secs
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.131 secs
| Error Gradle build terminated with error: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: could you use java8?

Comment: Thanks for comment/help. With j8, same issue :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your dependencies, something is incorrect about them and is causing the Servlet API and Spring JARs not to be on the compile classpath. Running `gradle dependencies` will help you identify the problem.

Comment: `$ gradle dependencies` not return any problem. I am using gradle 3.0 with sdkman.

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.142 secs`

Comment: I believe that is a environment problem, I have another PC with same OS, same JAVA version and works fine.

Comment: There any problem with .m2 folder, after remove .m2, everything works fine. I am trying simulate the problem.